# How to read the environment variable on adb device and not current system?

Tags: linux, bash, adb

If I try `adb shell $PWD` it reads the working directory of the current system and not the adb device.

How can I read the `$PWD` in the Android device instead via adb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something like

```
adb shell 'echo $PWD'
```

this will expand `$PWD` to the current working directory in the device.

Comment: Ah thanks, I just had to put it in quotes. I'll accept it soon.